# Transfer my Localhost API to heroku server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, deployment, server

I try to make HTTP request on my heroku app, online with nodejs. My app go online and all but don't include HTTP requests, then send me error when I click on the submit of my form button. However everything works fine on development environment.

What I have tried so far:

- localhost connection works on my PC, so the API it's okay in production.
- I have tried to make [herodku-domain]/api/[request] directly in my code but I get `404 Not Found`.
- In pakage.json I have made my proxy as "proxy": "https://domainame.herokuapp.com/" and it fails: `404 (Not Found)`.
- I have tried to include all my routes in my server.js file: `404 (Not Found)`
- I have tried to merge all my routers, models and schema files in my server.js file: `404 not found`.

A potential solution, if I understand well, is to set a NGINX host which will be then connected directly to my app and will be used as a reverse proxy.

My profile target my server.js file.

Here is my initial server.js file:

```
// middleware framework
var express = require("express")
// creaet an express application
var app = express() ;
var port = process.env.PORT || 7500 ;
var databaseName = "database";
// Parse incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers,
// available under the req.body property.
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
// Returns middleware that only parses json and only looks at requests
// where the Content-Type header matches the type option.
app.use(bodyParser.json()) ;


// Mongoose is a MongoDB object modeling tool
// designed to work in an asynchronous environment.
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
// provides you with a simple validation
// and query API to help you interact with your MongoDB database.
var db = mongoose.connection ;
// create a connection to [name] database
// mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/${databaseName}`)
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://IDs-iqg1t.mongodb.set/(...)=true')

// notify if connection succed or failed
db.on ('error', console.error.bind(console, "connection fails"))
db.once('open', function () {
 console.log(`mongoose : connection succeed on ${databaseName} database`);
});
// set the server on path of router folder
app.use('/api', require('./router/router.js'));

app.listen(, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: As provided code, you necessary don't need NGINX to set up a nodejs API on Heroku whether configuration files it's according Heroku requirements. In this case, what're the exceptions on Heroku console? If you want to set up a ReactJS project, the issue probably will be another

Comment: I mean, Heroku is a Paas, so maybe it's just that I got to use it as a framework and in their website they indicates a Mlab API. So,  I will try it and see. So far I have used MongoDB CLoud Atlas